# Laravel Mail::send fails to authenticate on the server but works locally

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

At some point recently the Mail::send function stopped working on our Laravel server. It still works when it's run locally though.

```
Mail::send(
    'emails.hello',
    $data,
    function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('admin@example.org', 'Admin');
        $message->to('recipient@example.org', 'Admin')
            ->replyTo($data['email'], $data['name'])
            ->subject('Contact Request');
    }
);
```

The .env configuration is exactly the same between the server and local instance, and I've run 'php artisan config:cache' to make sure the current .env file is loaded.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

They are both running Laravel 5.5.50. The server is running PHP 7.2.24, and locally the PHP version is PHP 7.4.33. The server is responding with the following error:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxx" using 3 possible authenticators. 
Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

I have 2-factor auth set up with my mail account and I am authenticating using an app password. Could this be a configuration issue somewhere in Laravel, or could it be a Google mail configuration issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you've ruled out the same code and configuration (username and app password) working from one location (i.e. on your local machine) and not working in another location (the server where it's been working for a while and now isn't working), this generally points to something external.

Remember that Google are using a lot of smarts to protect you and others against abuse and spam from folks using their email systems.

It seems quite likely that your server may have been blocked as part of Google's attempts to protect your account: https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620?sjid=10023023285085076167-EU#ts=9279979

Comment: I suspect that you are correct, and that the issue is stemming from some security setting in Google. Maybe generating a new app password would help?

Comment: Not sure. Worth a shot? But your app password is about you providing an app with specific access to your account. Google may be blocking the app itself, which they'll likely do through a few identifying markers, such as the app's key and maybe even the server's IP address. So it may not be that simple.

Comment: It may not even be a 'setting' in Google that you can control. You may need to reach out to their support to find out why your app/server is being blocked.

Comment: Well, I tried a new app password anyway and it did not help. Thanks for your input. I'll see about reaching out to Google support.

Comment: I'm curious if it might have anything to do with the fact that the Google account email is not an @gmail.com address? or is that irrelevant?

Comment: If it's running through Google's servers, I don't think that will make a difference

Comment: I submitted a support ticket to Google. They don't seem to make it very easy to get support though, so I'm not optimistic. I might just try going through a mail service like Mailgun instead of what's built into Laravel. We'll see if that makes a difference, but if that does resolve the problem that will also unfortunately mean paying the monthly fee for Mailgun. I looked back on our contact emails and the last time we got an email through our contact form was the end of September. It's a rather frustrating mystery.

Comment: I would ALWAYS recommend using one of those mail services. Mailgun have a pretty reasonable free tier which may be enough for your needs and even after that you can be billed per message rather than on a fixed-fee basis (iirc)

Comment: "Instead of what's built in to Laravel" - this seems like a misconception. The logic you're using to send mail through Gmail is the same that will be used to connect to Mailgun, the only difference is the method of connection (the 'driver' used to communicate with each provider) - I'd highly recommend an API over HTTP instead of SMTP - it's way more secure and granular

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of a free tier on the Mailgun website, but it does look like Mailjet has a free option so I might give that a try. Thanks again for all the info.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seemed to be caused by either a mistake in how the email system was set up on the original hosting or some limitations imposed by that hosting service.
I had a similar problem on my test hosting when setting up websites for clients. However, when I moved the website to a new hosting platform to make it live, the email sending worked perfectly.